# Dissappearing those pesky .x* config files

Tags: xorg, xdg

I'm trying to force as many of my dotfiles as possible to honor `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (and friends) instead of crapping all over my home directory. This involves some [minor](http://github.com/Soares/git.git) [tweaks](http://github.com/Soares/npm.git) to some common apps, but nothing too complicated. However, I'm having trouble wrestling all of `X`'s config files into `~/.config/X` directory or wherever I want it to go. Specifically, the ornery config files are:

```
.Xauthority
.Xdefaults
.xdvirc
.xinitrc
.xlog
.Xresources
.xscreensaver
.xsession-errors
```

I know that it will be quite difficult to avoid some of those sticking around in my home directory (`xinitrc`, cough cough) but it seems like all the others should be pretty mobile. In fact, many of them (`xlog`, `xsession-errors`) feel like they should be relocatable with an environment variable or two -- if my `zshrc` were loaded before `xinitrc`, that is.

Does anyone know an easy way to force the majority of these files to obey `XDG` and take their rightful place in `~/.config`? The cleanliness of my home directory would greatly appreciate any tips.

Comment: What method are you using to start X11 -- `xinit`/`startx` or a display manager?

Comment: startx, currently. No plans to switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `~/.Xauthority` is not a configuration file and only contains temporary authentication tokens, so it should go to `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` or `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` instead.

  If you are using `xinit` or `startx` to launch X11, you can relocate the Xauthority file by pointing `$XAUTHORITY` elsewhere in your `xinitrc`, then adding the `-auth newpath` argument to Xorg in your `xserverrc`.

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  exec /usr/bin/Xorg "$@" -nolisten tcp -auth "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/Xauthority"
  ```

  GDM stashes the Xauthority files deep inside `/var/run/gdm`.
- `~/.Xdefaults` is obsolete and should not be used. Its replacement is `~/.Xresources`.
- `~/.xdvirc` is unknown to me.
- `~/.xinitrc` can be relocated by giving the new path to `xinit`:

  ```
  startx ~/.config/X11/xinitrc
  ```
- `~/.xlog` is unknown to me.
- `~/.Xresources` is only read by `xrdb`, and can be relocated by telling `xrdb` to merge a different file in your `.xinitrc` or `.xprofile`:

  ```
  xrdb -merge ~/.config/X11/Xresources
  ```
- `~/.xscreensaver` will probably need to stay.
- `~/.xsession-errors` is only created by the GDM display manager. The latest Git version of GDM puts it in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`; otherwise it can be removed from within `.xprofile`. When using `xinit`, the xsession-errors file isn't created at all.

Comment: `~/.Xauthority` belongs into `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, not `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`. The former is guaranteed to be on a local file system (usually under `/run/user/$UID/` these days). Keeping `~/.Xauthority` under `$HOME`, which may be a networked file system, is an anachronism from the days before everyone used ssh to start remote X11 clients. This causes two problems. Firstly `sudo xterm` fails due to root squash. Secondly, if `$HOME` is on a Kerberized NFS mount with expired Kerberos ticket, your screen locker can no longer contact your X server to ask you for your password, thereby locking you out.